# Testing function calls in redux sagas

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, redux-saga

How can I test function calls in redux sagas? Having:

```
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1500);
  });
}

function* fooBar() {
  yield call(doSomething);
}

export function* (action) {
  yield call(fooBar);
}
```

How can I test this? I can't export the `fooBar` function inside the test, becuase I don't want export each function from my sagas. Also, what's the point of testing redux sagas? As far as I see this, it's just testing if every line gets executed, it doesn't really test any output etc.